# Beyond plural forms using the glossaries package

Tags: glossaries, glossaries-extra

Suppose I have the following `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\makeglossary

\newglossaryentry{snore}
{
  name={snore},
  description={to make an unpleasant noise while sleeping soundly}
}


\begin{document}

  I don't \gls{snore} when I'm sleeping.
  \printglossary

\end{document}
```

This compiles fine and I get the desired result. However I'd like to also use `\gls` on other forms of the verb "to snore". For instance, "I snored", "I'm snoring", "He snores".

I know there's a `\glspl` command which automatically generates the plural form. But that's not enough in this case.

Is there a way to make use of the `glossaries` package to achieve this? Or should I look to more sophisticated libraries?

Comment: Just being curious: Did you check the documentation here https://ctan.org/pkg/glossary?lang=en , and the category or topic here: https://ctan.org/topic/glossary ?

Comment: I mainly checked the official documentation for glossaries. I'd like to stick to the glossaries package if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The glossaries package has an excellent [FAQ](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/faq.php?action=view&category=glossaries):

> **My term has multiple plural forms, how can I deal with this?**
>
> Use
> the plural key for the plural term you are most likely to use, and use
> one of the user keys for the other plurals. For example:
>
> ```
> \newglossaryentry{cow}{name=cow,   description={a fully grown female
>    of any bovine animal (plural cows, archaic plural kine)},  
>    user1={kine}}
>
> \let\glsaltpl\glsuseri
> ```
>
> You can now use `\glspl` for the first plural and
> `\glsaltpl` for the second plural. There are six user keys, so this
> method can be used for other grammatical constructs as well. As from
> version 4.0, you can also define your own keys via `\glsaddkey`. See the
> section Additional Keys in the user manual for further details.
>
> **How do I define different grammatical parts for an entry?**
>
> As with
> **My term has multiple plural forms, how can I deal with this?** you can
> use one of the user keys (such as user1) or you can define your own
> key. However, this can lead to a large number of extra keys. You may
> find it easier to simply use `\glsdisp` or `\glslink`. For example, with
> the following definition:
>
> ```
> \newglossaryentry{run}{name=run,description={...}}
> ```
>
> Then you can do:
>
> ```
> I \glsdisp{run}{ran} to the shops. They are \glsdisp{ran}{running} to
> catch the bus.
> ```

(I think that the second `\glsdisp` has a typo and should be `glsdisp{run}{running}`.)

Comment: `\glsdisp` is pretty much exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is one possibility.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\makeglossary

\newglossaryentry{snore}
{   name={snore},
    description={\emph{Verb} To make an unpleasant noise while sleeping soundly}
}

\newglossaryentry{snored}
{   name={snored},
    description={Past Tense of \textbf{\gls{snore}}}
}

\newglossaryentry{snoring}
{   name={snoring},
    description={Present Continuous Tense of \textbf{\gls{snore}}}
}

\newglossaryentry{snores}
{   name={snores},
    description={Simple Tense of \textbf{\gls{snore}}}
}


\begin{document}
    
    I don't \gls{snore} when I'm sleeping.
    
    I \gls{snored}.
    
    I'm \gls{snoring}.
    
    He \gls{snores}.    
    
    \printglossary
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is not what I'm looking for. I need all the variants of the infinitive "to snore" to point to the same term in the glossary. You can imagine, for instance, that "snore", "snores", "snored" and "snoring" would not be separate entries in a dictionary.

Comment: @user32882 How many variants? Can you make a complete list?

Comment: An arbitrary amount of variants.